# Is there any explorer.exe problem in windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, explorer

```
s += "<p style=\"text-align: left;\"><a href=\"javascript:window.print()\">PRINT</a></p>";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"CheckForm.html", s);
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "CheckForm.html";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I'm having a trouble when I tried to open my C# windows application in Windows 7 otherwise there is no problem.

I couldn't open explorer.exe in Windows 7 with above code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you opening a webpage in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Because every computer has explorer.

Comment: Definitely not every computer. And Windows Explorer != Internet Explorer. See my answer for details.

Comment: Actually, your code works for me on Windows 7. The HTML document is opened in my default browser. What exactly is the trouble you are talking about? Have you tried to use an absolute path for your document?

Comment: internet explorer is not opening when I tried above code.

Comment: @sml: Is anything happening? Your sample will not start *Internet Explorer*, it will open the HTML document in the *default* browser (as explorer.exe is your shell). Probably your default browser is not properly configured? What application is associated with .html files on your machine?

Comment: above code is working fine with ie6,7,firefox,chrome. But not in ie8. I couldn't find any solution about that. My application is chrome but I'm using explorer for this project.

Answer (score 3):

To open an HTML file, you should simply call `Process.Start` with the path to the file, like this:

```
Process.Start(@"CheckForm.html");
```

This will open the file in the default program.  (Typically IE or Firefox)

Comment: +1, however, just an additional remark: This works only if `startInfo.UseShellExecute` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) is set to `true`, which luckily is the default, so in the sample above you don't have to worry.

Comment: So what should be the working one ?

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "CheckForm.html";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

this one ?

Comment: You should write `Process.Start(@"CheckForm.html");`

Answer (score 1):

`explorer.exe` is the Windows Explorer or desktop system. You probably want to open the Internet Explorer, which process name would be `iexplore.exe`.

Windows Explorer was previously integrated with Internet Explorer, so that – depending on the path you enter – the program switches to the wanted application. IE for urls, and Windows Explorer for local paths. That's probably why it worked before.

However with Vista I think, the integration was loosened, so this won't work any longer.

Comment: explorer.exe also is the shell. So there is nothing wrong with the sample code posted by @sml.

Comment: Yeah, explorer plays a lot of roles. But still from the code it rather seems he wants to open Internet Explorer, and not the default application for html files.

Comment: Well, from the comments it seems that he wants IE, but from the code he will get the application that is associated with .html files.

Comment: Well my answer is based on the idea that he mixed up explorer with iexplore :P

Comment: Using `ieplore.exe` however requires passing a full path as argument, i.e. `startInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "CheckForm.html");`